# Multiply by two elements of the matrix

Tags: c, arrays

The program would multiply by two elements of the following matrix:

```
   4 7 8 
   6 9 1 
   5 0 3
```

(No has an compilaton error, algoritm correct)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){ 
    int arr_num[3][3]={ {4,7,8},{6,9,1},{5,0,3}};
    int i=0,j=0;

    for (i=0;i<=2; i++)
         for (j=0;j<=2; j++)
              arr_num[i][j]=arr_num[i][j]*2;

              for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
              {
                  for (j=0;j<=2;j++)
                       printf("%2d ",arr_num[i][j]);
                       printf("\n");
    }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please correct your indention to clarify your intentions... (i.e. do you INTEND for your 3rd "for" statement to be subordinate to the 2nd "for" statement or is it just a formating error?),,, better yet, add appropriate opening and closing braces on all "for" statements.

Comment: What is a `strip error`??

Comment: Don't use `conio.h` and `getch();`. That makes your code 100% non-portable to anything other than windoze. Instead, delete `#include <conio.h>` and replace `getch();` with `getchar();`. That will do the same thing to keep your terminal open on windoze until you press the 'Any Key' button and be 100% portable.  Even better, wrap the `getchar();` call in `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)`, that way it will only be called on windoze.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the wrong loop counter in the inner for loop that computes the new matrix value (you should increment j, not i).